# Personalizar caminho de saída dos arquivos convertidos pelo gulp markdown it

Tags: javascript, gulp, markdown

Eu estava acompanhando [esse passo a passo](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_step-2-create-a-simple-gulp-task), e então surgiu a necessidade de que os arquivos markdown convertidos para html estivesse em outra pasta.

Veja o código do arquivo `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var markdown = require('gulp-markdown-it');

gulp.task('markdown', function() {
    return gulp.src('**/*.md')
        .pipe(markdown())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(f) {
            return f.base;
        }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['markdown'], function() {
    gulp.watch('**/*.md', ['markdown']);
});
```

Considere a seguinte estrutura do projeto:

```
 meuProjeto
 |_ .vscode
 |  |_ tasks.json
 |_ folder1
 |  |_ fileA.md
 |_ node_modules
 |_ gulpfile.js
 |_ package-lock.json
 |_ sample.md
```

Quando coloco a tarefa para executar, após alguma mudança nos arquivos `.md`, tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
 meuProjeto
 |_ .vscode
 |  |_ tasks.json
 |_ folder1
 |  |_ fileA.html
 |  |_ fileA.md
 |_ node_modules
 |_ gulpfile.js
 |_ package-lock.json
 |_ sample.html
 |_ sample.md
```

Perceba que os arquivos `.html` estão juntamente com os arquivos originais `.md`. Meu objetivo é separa-los da seguinte forma em uma pasta `build`:

```
 meuProjeto
 |_ .vscode
 |  |_ tasks.json
 |_ build
 |  |_sample.html
 |  |_ folder1
 |     |_ fileA.html
 |_ folder1
 |  |_ fileA.md
 |_ node_modules
 |_ gulpfile.js
 |_ package-lock.json
 |_ sample.md
```

Seria muito bom se as pastas fossem criadas automaticamente.

Tentei alterar o código da tarefa do Gulp, mas não tive sucesso. É realmente possível fazer o que estou querendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta na função `gulp.dest` retornar a pasta desejada. Ainda é possível especificar alguma pasta para ignorar:

```
gulp.task('markdown', function() {
    return gulp.src(['**/*.md', '!node_modules/**'])
        .pipe(markdown())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```